# React Native Image is not updating right away

Tags: reactjs, react-native, digital-ocean

I have problem on my Image component, happens right now when I update the image, the image is not updating right away even if I refresh the whole project still the image stock on the last image. I found out that I need to clear the storage and clear cache the application before the exact image will shown.

**Problem**: Image is not updating right away, I need to clear the storage and clear cache the application first before the exact image will shown.

**Platform**: React Native

**Code**:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetTransaction({ id: transaction_data?.id, token: auth_access?.results?.access_token })).then((res) => {
      setProofDeliveryImg(res?.payload?.results?.bookings?.[0]?.proof_of_delivery)
    })
  }, [])

ProofDeliveryImg != '' ? (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlerOpenCamera()}>
    <Image mt="5" source={{
      uri: `${REACT_APP_API_STORAGE_URL}/`+ProofDeliveryImg
      }} alt={ProofDeliveryImg} key={`${REACT_APP_API_STORAGE_URL}/`+ProofDeliveryImg} style={{ width: width - 90, height: 200 }} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Is this behavior the same for iOS and android ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl yes your correct. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: use ```cache: "reload" ``` property in your image source as documented [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#imagesource)

Comment: @sushrut619 i tried this one, but still not working.

Comment: Based on the document cache: "reload" use in IOS.

Comment: Don't have definitive answer but would you try changing the key prop every time your uri changes. Also what do 'mt', 'alt' and 'key' props do? I don't see them listed in react-native image [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image). If you have a list of 'ProofDeliveryImg' components being rendered then shouldn't the key be a prop for 'TouchableOpacity' ? Is it possible that you are using Image component from some UI library and the library has some sort of caching behavior override ?